# CheckBox after TextBox(in the same line) Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been searching for this from a long time but couldnt find a good article. I am using the following code-

```
$this->addElement('Text', 'to',array( 'label'=>'My Text Box')); 
$this->addElement('checkbox', 
                  'my checkbox', 
                   array( 'label'=>'', 
                         'decorators' => array(
                                array('Label', array('placement' => 'PREPEND')), 
                                array('ViewHelper') ) )
                  );
```

Instead the check box comes a line after the text box. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'APPEND' instead of 'PREPEND' if you want your label after your checkbox